# add actions to action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So I did exactly what i suppose to do according to the android development training but still i cant see the actions on the action bar, instead they are in the overflow menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and also i set that:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

what can i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a bug. You should apply another namespace:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always force the menu entries to appear by changing `myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to `myapp:showAsAction="always"`

Don't forget to define your app namespace before: `xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Quoting from docs for the namespace change:

`The showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.`

Maybe the name of your app is too big and that's why the menu entries don't appear.

Comment: Also, unless you have a specific search icon in your drawables you want to use, you can use a standard one from android: `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"`. It took me a bit to find it :)